# Find the curve that encloses the largest surface area

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

> Among the curves of given length $l$, at the upper half-plane, passing through the points $(-a, 0)$ and $(a, 0)$ , find the one that encloses the largest surface area together with the space $[-a,a]$.

I believe the answer for this problem is that there is no such curve because one can always find one another curve than encloses a larger surface area than the previous one. Until now, I have only minimized functionals and, thus, I have no clue from where to begin to prove my case in this problem. My questions are:

1. Is my answer the right one?
2. What can I do to solve this kind of problem?

I hope that I've been clear. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your answer is wrong, because the curve length is fixed.

Comment: of course... I missed that.. so this is an isoperimetric problem. But how can I find the fuctional that I have to maximize..? I see that the restriction here is that the curve must have a certain length  which is l but I don't know what to do to find the Lagrange fuction..

Comment: If $A$ is the integral giving the area and $L$ is the integral giving the length, you can do as with Lagrange multipliers and seek a minimum of $A+\lambda L$, choosing then $\lambda$ such as $L=l$.

Comment: See also here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/isop.shtml